# Cocos2D and Google IOS Analytics not working

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement Google Analytics SDK, but I am getting the following message:

```
2014-03-16 18:24:18.469 colorcorner[20756:60b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2014-03-16 18:24:34.497 colorcorner[20756:8617] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03c -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:275): No pending hits.
```

The thing is that I can't see any data at Google's Dashboard, not even in "Real Time".

At app delegate's:

.h

```
#import "GAI.h"
```

.m

```
// Registering for Google Analytics
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

// Initialize tracker.
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-49038599-1"];
```

GameScene.h:

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

GameScene.m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
...
...
        // Registering Google Analytics
        id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
        [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"MainScreen"];
        [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
...
...
}
```

It is a little bit different form a regular app, working with views and so on.

Any ideas for a possible solution?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I haven't found anybody with this issue while using Cocos2D.

After some tests I came to a conclusion:

I cannot use the default tracker with the following sentence:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
```

I have to say to the API what is the ID Tracker once again, like:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-1111111-1"];
```

Now it is working!

Comment: I have the same problem, and still cannot fix. Could you explain in detail the meaning of action `I have to say to the API what is the ID Tracker once again, like:`? I'm not sure what I should to do with your advice.

Comment: I mean that I have to remind the API that I am using that TrackingID everytime. The API documentation says that after telling the system what ID to use for the first time I would only have to use the "defaultTracker" in the future. Which by my experience isn't true.